# QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 0

Tags: python, qt, pyside, 3dsmax

I started watching some tutorials for Python and QT (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eq7__6y0jwo&index=3&list=PL19DCiIwVefyQxlDTWlXQ4lnZDPW6_r-q) but I'm getting this error "QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 0" and I can't figure out why. The idea is that I want to have a window that works in 3dsMax, Modo and maybe as a standalone (Both 3dsMax and Modo come with PySide).

Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class PaletteListModel (QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, colors=[], parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._colors = colors


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    listView = QtGui.QListView()
    listView.show()

    red = QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)
    green = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0)
    blue = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255)

    model = PaletteListModel([red, green, blue])

    listView.setModel(model)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I see wrong with your code is you are inheriting from QAbstractListModel without implementing the abstract methods.

From the documentation here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#details

> When subclassing QAbstractListModel, you must provide implementations
>   of the rowCount() and data() functions. Well behaved models also
>   provide a headerData() implementation.

Are leaving out any code? Do you ever create a QPainter object?

Comment: Thanks Aaron! That was so stupid of me. That fixed it. In the tutorial he hadn't implemented those two methods in his first Run so I thought it was ok to test it too before going any further.

Comment: No problem, if your problem is solved please accept the answer :)

Comment: gotcha! First day on stack overflow too.. I was trying to up-vote this morning, but I wasn't allowed because I don't have enough reputation points.  again thanks  :)